# How to prevent a fixed position header from extending beyond the width of the browser

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed header at the top of my page which should be width: 100%, but it extends beyond the width of the window. Can anyone tell me what I am missing here? I have tried reseting the parent divs to 0 margin. I have tried encasing the header in a parent div. I tried adding box-sizing as was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984173/fixed-position-footer-at-100-width-extends-past-window-to-right) which didn't help either. In every case, the header continues to extend to the right of the browser window.

html:

```
<body>
  <div class='header'>
    <h1 class='name'>some name</h1>
    <button class='link-button' type='menu'>Links</button>
    <div class='navigation-links'>
      <a href="#link" class='header-link'>some link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>content</h3>
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(27,62,111,1);
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Thanks for you help!

Comment: It looks fine for me in Chrome. Maybe add a screenshot?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with the code you posted.

Comment: Works fine for me in chrome also.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I figured out why you couldn't reproduce it. It was the padding on something much further down the page, which I didn't include in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp

the css property max-width: 100% should limit it inside the window - unless the surrounding container allows it to extend beyond the screens limits.

Also you might have widths set inside your header that are causing it to be bigger than expected.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce with your code.  You may be setting a min-width to another div somewhere else.